# Is it reasonable to expect two shared libraries built on two identical platforms?

Tags: c++, linux, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

If I build the same source code,  link to the same version of the same libraries,  with the same tool chain ( same compiler, linker etc , GCC 4.4), with the same version of the same operating system,   ( Centos 5 Linux in my case) but on two different machines;

Is it reasonable to assume that binaries produced should be identical?

The context behind this is my code has 'undefined behaviour'  which 'works' on one configuration but not the other, the obvious answer is to fix this, but I would be interested to know if my assumption that binaries produced should be the identical is correct.

I notice a few hundred bytes difference in size,  the location of the symbols shown with the 'nm' command differ slightly, even though the symbols are the same.

Comment: And you have all other components that the shared library depends on identical too - such as glibc for the most obvious one?

Comment: If you build the same source code on the same machine in the same way but at a different time, is the result identical?

Comment: The short answer is really that "if everything is EXACTLY the same", then you should get the same result [aside from if "date" and "build number" and similar information 'supplied at compile-time' gets included in the binary - but that should only affect that information in itself].

Comment: I suspect, however, that SOMETHING is different between your systems - the version of compiler isn't EXACTLY the same, or the glibc isn't the same [or not built with the same compiler, etc].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would expect a date and/or meta data to vary slightly even between builds on the same host.

You also neglected to mention compiler flags, (optimization and `#define`s from the command line for example).

I would however initially suspect the files should come out to the same size, which leads us to the conclusion that *something* is *not* the same across the two systems. The most likely candidates are system headers (just one root-level feature in the OS install could cause an entirely different view of these files) and any dependent libraries.

You can check that the headers are the same by preprocessing with `g++ -E` or similar. You can also follow the library path and confirm that the linked-to files are identical on each system.

Comment: Normally object files contain timestamps, and also strings identifying the operating system and compiler.